# Jquery Mobile parent popup div close

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a button inside a jquery mobile popup div. I will like to set a onclick javascript function to let the popup div close without using the id of the div once the button clicked. Any solution?

Comment: `$(this).closest(".ui-popup").popup("close");`.

Answer (score 0):

Can call parent too:

```
$(this).parent(".ui-popup").popup("close");
```